# Intersection of a line and a curve. Why is my reasoning incorrect?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the intersection of the line $y = 3x - 1$ with the curve $x^2 + x$.

I equate the line and the curve to find the point of intersection: $y = 3x - 1 = x^2 + x$.

$\Rightarrow y = x^2 - 2x + 1$

Here is where I think my reasoning is incorrect, but I do not understand why.

To find the $y$ coordinate, let $x = 0$: $y = 1$.

To find the $x$ coordinate, let $y = 0$: $x^2 -2x + 1 = 0$.

$\Rightarrow x = 1$

However, the correct point of intersection is $x = 1$, $y = 2$.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me understand why my reasoning is incorrect and what the correct reasoning is.

Thank you.

Comment: $y=3x-1$ and $y=x^2+x$ so $x^2-2x+1=(x^2+x)-(3x-1)=y-y=0$ not $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct, up to the point of "let $x=0$ and $y=0$".

To find the intersection point, you would instead set $y=0$ and solve $x^2-2x+1=0\Rightarrow x=1$.

It's because that you set the two equations equal to each other, you get$$\text{equation 1}=\text{equation 2}\implies\text{equation 1}-\text{equation 2}=0\tag1$$
So the $y$ variable isn't there. Really, it should be

---

$$\begin{align*} & y=x^2+x\tag{2}\\ & y=3x-1\tag{3}\end{align*}$$
Setting them equal eliminates $y$$$\begin{align*} & x^2+x=3x-1\\ & \implies x^2-2x+1=0\\ & \implies x=1\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's be a little more specific here:

$$y_1=3x-1\\y_2=x^2+x$$

If we want to find the intersection, then

$$y_2=y_1\implies0=y_2-y_1$$

This is why the second method is correct, but the first is not.

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding things, we have, $$y = x^2+x...(1)$$ $$y = 3x-1.....(2)$$ Subtracting the two equations, we get $0=x^2-2x+1$ not $y= x^2-2x+1$. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have two equations of the form y= ..., some function in terms of x.

For now, just ignore the y entirely and focus on finding the x-coordinate at the intersection point.

Set the equations for your line and curve equal to one another. You should now be able to solve for x.

Now you have an x-coordinate. You also have an equation for a line, where each x-coordinate has exactly one y-coordinate (with the exception of a vertical line, which we know this is not).

Plug the x-coordinate into your equation for the line and solve for the corresponding y-value.